# How to fill pdf form using javascript with custom font using pdf-lib?

Tags: javascript

I have a custom pdf with form inside it and I wanna fill it with values.

It wasn't that hard to use some font, but I can't figure out how to set `fontSize` for field, because is does matter in some of the fields.

Here's my code atm:

```js
export async function stampPdfLib(payload: {
  templatePath: string,
  data: { [key: string]: string },
  version: string,
}): Promise<Uint8Array> {
  const formPdfBytes = await fetch(payload.templatePath).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());
  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes);
  const timesRomanFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.TimesRoman);

  const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
  form.updateFieldAppearances(timesRomanFont); // I could set font, but ...

  form.getTextField('field_name').setText('a'); // I couln't set fontSize

  const savedBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
  return savedBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every form field type (`PDFCheckBox`, `PDFTextField`,...) of `PDFForm` has readonly property `acroField` of appropriate type (`PDFAcroCheckBox`, `PDFAcroText`,...). In those types might be hidden exactly what you are after.
In the `node_modules/pdf-lib/src` you can find form field  types under `/api/form`, and for `acroField` types you can navigate to `/core/acroform`.
However in this case you have method exposed directly for textField - `textField.setFontSize(number)` (`v1.16.0` of `pdf-lib`).

Without any settings - `default behavior`:

> [image]

`form.getTextField('field_name').setFontSize(11)` or `form.getTextField('field_name').acroField.setFontSize(11);`

> [image]

`form.getTextField('field_name').setFontSize(20)` or
`form.getTextField('field_name').acroField.setFontSize(20);`

> [image]

Of course, you have to take care of your input field size (in case you font size is too large).

Comment: I have a lot of form fields, can I not set the font size on all fields, instead of each individually?

Comment: @conor909 i can not see such a method in documentation.